# XPath Exception SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("component.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        string path4 = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();

        XmlNode nodeToRemove = doc.SelectSingleNode(path4);
        XmlNode parentNode = nodeToRemove.ParentNode;
        parentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);
 }
```

i use following code for remove node in my xml but it generate following errors. please help me.

this is the part of my xml.  i  want to remove user selected path Entry. for select path i was generate treeview. variable path4  come from treeview selected path.

```
<WindowEntries>
<WindowEntry>
  <Name>tbwUnitOverview</Name>
  <View>TRN_UNIT</View>
  <LU>TrnUnit</LU>
  <DefaultWindowText />
  <Flags>0</Flags>
</WindowEntry>
<WindowEntry>
  <Name>tbwBrandOverView</Name>
  <View>TRN_BRAND</View>
  <LU>TrnBrand</LU>
  <DefaultWindowText />
  <Flags>0</Flags>
</WindowEntry>
<WindowEntry>
  <Name>tbwProductCategory</Name>
  <View>TRN_PROD_CATEGORY</View>
  <LU>TrnProdCategory</LU>
  <DefaultWindowText />
  <Flags>0</Flags>
</WindowEntry>
<WindowEntry>
  <Name>tbwModel</Name>
  <View>TRN_MODEL</View>
  <LU>TrnModel</LU>
  <DefaultWindowText />
  <Flags>0</Flags>
</WindowEntry>
</WindowEntries>
```

[image: error window] [image: error2]

Comment: can you post your xml as well?

also try / instead of \

also

Comment: Do you know which node you are actually removing? Could you show us the Path and the XML?

Comment: Please post the exception information as text, not as am image.

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5 or higher? If so, I'd suggest using LINQ to XML instead - in many cases it makes life a lot easier.

Comment: exception is, selected path is invalid token.   "XmlNode nodeToRemove = doc.SelectSingleNode(path4);"  nodeToRemove variable always null. path4 pass value to nodeToRemove variable .

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the code should be

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("component.xml"))
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);
    string path4 = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();

    // now replace '\' by '/'
    path4 = path4.Replace('\\', '/');

    XmlNode nodeToRemove = doc.SelectSingleNode(path4);
    XmlNode parentNode = nodeToRemove.ParentNode;
    parentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);
}
```

1. Don't use `new XmlTextReader()` unless you're still on .NET 1.1. It's been replaced with `XmlReader.Create()`.
2. You need a `using` block around the reader to ensure it is cleaned up, regardless of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Hosang mentionned, it is because your are using `\` instead of `/`.
Try :

```
path4 = path4.Replace("\\", "/");
```

this should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath must be in correct form: /node1/node2/.../nodeN

Fix like this, it works :)

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("data.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        string path4 = treeView1.SelectedNode.FullPath.ToString();       

        // now replace '\' by '/'
        path4 = path4.Replace('\\', '/');
        // appending '/' at beginning
        path4 = "/" + path4;           

        XmlNode nodeToRemove = doc.SelectSingleNode(path4);
        XmlNode parentNode = nodeToRemove.ParentNode;
        parentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToRemove);
```

Please refer to Xpath syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: How one can unit test generating or parsing of xml files to avoid such a issues? I saw you post from few years ago about xml but you didn't mention any testing at the time. Do you have experience with it? Any ideas to share? Thanks